# How to refresh a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` with some data. You can add rows through a separate window. The `DataContext` is the same, a `LINQ-to-SQL` object. Binding is also the same, I bind the `ItemsSource` property to a table.

In the other window, when the user clicks on `Save`, I create a row programmatically and add it using `InsertOnSubmit`. After that I use the `DataContext`'s `SubmitChanges` method.

My problem is that the `DataGrid` isn't updated. If I restart the application I can see the new row, so it's in the database, but I couldn't find a way to refresh the `DataGrid`.

So far I've tried to use `UpdateTarget` on the `BindingExpression` of the `DataGrid`, but it didn't help. I've also tried `dataGrid.Items.Refresh()` — same result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason it's not updating is that `LINQ-to-SQL` doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so WPF has no way to tell that the `ItemsSource` has been updated. The least terrifying way to fix this, is to copy your LINQ-to-SQL results to an `ObservableCollection` - when you do the Insert, also add to the observable collection. Then you'll see the update.

Comment: Your solution is obviously working. I just thought I could get away with simple XAML binding markup.

Comment: If we use a ObservableCollection to be a bridge between linq to sql and the control, then how can we use SubmitChanges() to post back the result back to database ?

Comment: @MemoryLeak - so here's the tricky bit; not only do you want to know when the *collection* changes (i.e. what INotifyCollectionChanged), you also want to know when any of the *items* change. So you need to subscribe to the collection change, then on add/remove, subscribe to each item's INotifyPropertyChanged. *Then* you have to decide what to save based on which notifications you're getting

Answer (score 67):

try datagrid.Items.Refresh() from here http://programmer.wrighton.org/2009/01/wpf-datagrid-items-refresh.html

Comment: Thank you :) I tried rebinding the same source but it did not update the data. Setting ItemsSource = null and then the correct source did an update but caused the SelectionChanged to be fired. The Items.Refresh() worked perfect!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into same problem and found that best place for ObservableCollection is DataContext. It has some partial methods generated by designer that can be used to update collection. This code works pretty well:

```
partial class DataClassesDataContext
{
    private ObservableCollection<Task> taskCollection;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Task> TaskView { get; private set; }

    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        taskCollection = new ObservableCollection<Task>(Tasks);
        TaskView = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Task>(taskCollection);
    }

    partial void InsertTask(Task instance)
    {
        taskCollection.Add(instance);
        this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
    }

    partial void DeleteTask(Task instance)
    {
        taskCollection.Remove(instance);
        this.ExecuteDynamicDelete(instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to refresh your LINQ-to-SQL DataContext.  The DataContext's won't properly recognize the new row even after a submit changes.  You need to dispose the DataContext you have and create a new one.  In most cases DataContext should be used for one short operation and not as a long standing object.

Comment: Your solution is very similar to Pwninstein's. Unfortunately the result is the same, as the DataContextChanged event doesn't make the DataGrid refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a case when you have to reload a grid in another window , you can simply close that window and invoke it again.

Answer (score 0):

Or just invoke the search code again (usually the search button)> I have solved it in my case like this.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `Items.Refresh()` is not working for me.
What did work was to make my underlying collection inherit `ObservableCollection` and then call its `Add` method.

```
((ContactUIObjects)dgrdContacts.ItemsSource).Add(new ContactUIObject(o));
```

`ContactUIObjects` is just the grids underlying collection.