# Rebinding to WPF Datagrid's Datacontext

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datacontext

I can't believe I am stumped with this fairly straightforward thing.  I originally posted this in the WPF datagrid codeplex discussions but got no response.  So I am trying here:

I can't seem to find a way to do this.  I create a datagrid whose datacontext is initially filled with rows from a table.  I have implemented a search functionality that will return some rows based on a condition.  Suppose I want to display only those rows, how do I destroy the initially created datacontext and add the newly filtered collection?

I naively started doing it like this:

(Late Edit: I can't seem to type Generics code here -- the cast in the following line is suppoed to cast datagrid.Items to MyType (for example))

IEnumerable rows = datagrid.Items.Cast();

IEnumerable filteredRows = rows.Where(row => row.someCondition == true);

how do I now make my datagrid display only the filteredRows?  Just doing:

datagrid.DataContext = null;

datagrid.DataContext = filteredRows;

doesn't work (it even smells stupid for some reason).

I also need to do the reverse (once I get this working).  Some buttonclick should allow the user to "clear" the search results and re-plug the DataContext back to "rows" (in the above snippet).

What am I missing?

Comment: what happens when you assign dataGrid.DataContext = filteredRows? This should work, I thought.

Comment: If you add `` ticks around your code you should be able to post generic code as well.

Comment: Apparently the way to do it is to assign that delegate (which filters the rows) directly to the Filter property of the Items collection.  I am going to try this once I get to work.  I will report back on how things turn out.

Answer (score 3):

I came across similar issue. Needed to re-apply converters on my DataGrid after changing some style values.

For me this worked:

```
myGrid.Items.Refresh()
```

It appears to re-apply all of the rules so it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

myGrid.Items.Refresh() worked for me too, just re-set the context before

```
public void GridExamsRefresh()
{
  grdExamenes.ItemsSource = (this.objPacienteOfContext).Exams;
  grdExamenes.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some similar problems were encountered in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930350/how-to-refresh-a-wpf-datagrid) In the comments, he even says setting the datacontext to null and then re-assigning it doesn't work.

Perhaps you have to modify the items collection as mentioned in that answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the ItemsSource property?