# using Datagrid.Items.Refresh() from viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am using MVVM pattern.
I want to use datagrid's refresh method .
I have also gone through following link and its useful:
[How to refresh a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930350/how-to-refresh-a-wpf-datagrid)

but my problem is : I have created one datagrid object in viewmodel like this:

```
    public DataGrid ActiveGrid=new DataGrid();
public void RefreshGrid()
        {
           View.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                ActiveGrid.Items.Refresh()

                ));
        }
```

and my datagrid's itemsource is already bound to another collection e.g

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ActiveGrid"
                      IsReadOnly="True"                      
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveCallCollection}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveGridCollection,
                                             Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single"
                      Visibility="{Binding IsActiveCallsSelected,
                                           Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
```

How can I bind ActiveGrid to xaml datagrid.

Comment: I'm not sure why are you creating this in your viewmodel. If you want to update the datagrid because youa added items to ActiveCallCollection you need to use the INotifyPropertyChanged to tell the UI something has changed in that collection. If you are indeed databinding a collection and adding items dynamicly I suggest you use ObservableCollection. If you add an item to this collection it will notify itself already that it has obtained new items.

Comment: my ActiveCallCollection is actually an ObservableCollection. i have also tried with INotifyPropertyChanged. but datagrid gets updated when I toggle the rows, its not working as soon as data comes in ObservableCollection. Or can I use refresh() method directly in my xaml Window. and how to?

Comment: well to answer your question "How can I bind ActiveGrid to xaml datagrid." You can remove the datagrid from xaml make it a ContentPresenter and make the ActiveGrid a public Property.
`<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ActiveGrid}" >` but I think thats not the correct option here. If you are created a NEW observable collection **after the constructor** you do need to NotifyPropertyChanged the collection.

Comment: my requirement is there must be datagrid. so is there any option to bind my ActiveGrid object to datagrid other than using ItemsSource

Comment: The DataGrid is not an appropriate control for displaying live updating data.  What happens if a user is entering data in a field and it gets updated in the background to blow away the user's edits?

Comment: Also, you care about INotifyCollectionChanged on your ItemsSource in this case.  The objects contained withing the observable collection should be the implementors of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: there are lot of properties in my class. so if I use INotifyCollectionChanged. I will have to raise propertychanged event on each of them. right? it will be overhead

Comment: Have you measured the overhead?  How many properties?  If you're talking about 20, so what?  If you're talking about 200, redesign your interface.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a DataGrid object in your ViewModel then its not MVVM anymore. you better ask what you want to achieve, so we can help you.

if you bind to a OberservableCollection - you should to this **once**! all changes(add, remove) are then reflected in your datagrid.

pls post your code where you create/alter your collection

Comment: actually you are right. but tell me from where I can call ActiveGrid.Items.Refresh(). because we dont want it to be called from *.xaml.cs.  still I can post more code if you want

Comment: well if you do mvvm and binding to observablecollection you did not need to call refresh. your items are updated automatically. you should post what line of code does not update your grid.

Comment: the line of code in your viewmodel of course :) maybe we can find a solution then

Comment: @deathrace.dj A `DataGrid` is a UI component, therefore it should not be mixed in with your data classes (ViewModels). Also, anything related to the UI only, such as refreshing a control, should be done in the code-behind the View

Answer (score 0):

If your using the MVVM design pattern, your view model should not have a DataGrid

Instead your `View` should have a `DataGrid`, and it should be bound to an `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel.

Be sure you **bind** the `ItemsSource` property and not **set** it, or the changes to the `ObservableCollection` may not automatically update in the UI

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ActiveGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"                      
          ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveCallCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected ActiveCall}" 
          SelectionMode="Single"
          Visibility="{Binding IsActiveCallsSelected,
                               Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
          d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
```